# safari like downloading in iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, safari, uiviewanimation, download

I need help on an animation like `safari` uses for downloading. 
When we click on a downloadable link, the animation will start where safari img will pop from the clicked position to the right side of the safari window where downloading will be shown in down arrow mark. 
How can I achieve this in `iOS` and I need to do it for iPad/iPhone.

Comment: Like Safari for OS X or Safari for iOS?

Comment: I did [a blog post about how to replicate the iOS "Open in Background" animation (as seen in Safari for iOS)](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/23234805389/unobtrusive-hints-of-joy) a while back. Does that help you? In short, there is a lot of work (some is already done for you in that post).

Comment: You should be able to modify the code from my [blog post (linked to above)](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/23234805389/unobtrusive-hints-of-joy) to animate and scale the image down to another point on the screen. Most of the code should still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

ou have to use animation within the IBAction. using one of 
Core Animation
OpenGL ES
Quartz 2D

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know _how_ to do it, not what technologies to use.

Comment: I need a simple animation. don't want opengl stuff. it should be like a curve kind where the animation ll start from the button center and it animation ll goes top and to the destination